# Local binary pattern and principal component analysis - Matlab

Tags: matlab, pca, matlab-cvst

I have a question regarding local binary pattern and principal component analysis. I understand both the methods separately but I do not know how to combine them.

The Matlab output for LBP features can be a vector back to 1-by- N feature vector as shown in the link: http://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/ref/extractlbpfeatures.html

If I generate LBP features vectors of images (50, for example), how can I perform the PCA? Is this a valid approach to use?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have `M` images (say, 50), and `N` features for each image, you could see that as `M` points in `N` dimensions. You could use PCA to reduce your dataset to `N-r` dimensions, where `r` is the number of dimensions to be removed.